# AppConfig module fails to install (cpan)

Tags: perl, cpan, template-toolkit

cpan AppConfig

Everything works out; tests are passed - but no AppConfig!

Here is the tail end of the output:

```
Running make install
Appending installation info to /root/perl5/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/perllocal.pod
  ABW/AppConfig-1.66.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/make install  -- OK
```

Note there is nothing about copying the module into its rightful place. I am hesitant to start moving files around.  Anyone run into this?

Answer (score 1):

I get the exact same behaviour when AppConfig is already installed and I run `cpan -f AppConfig` (`f` = force).

Since no installed file pertaining to the AppConfig distribution changed, ExtUtils::Install will not copy from `blib` to the target location. `perllocal.pod` is always appended to.